# Angular material md-select - cant open the box with selected user

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material, md-select

Hi the selectbox is show the selected item but i cant open the dropdown at all 
I am using form in the mdpanel 
its not working in dialog on mdpanel 
how can i fix it

i need form with edit user and i need select box that initialize with one of the user param

```
  users :[
            { id: 1, name: 'Bob' },
            { id: 2, name: 'Alice' },
            { id: 3, name: 'Steve' }
          ],
         selectedUser : { id: 1, name: 'Bob' }
```

html:

```
   <md-select ng-model="ctrl.selectedUser" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}">
          <md-option ng-value="user" ng-repeat="user in ctrl.users">{{ user.name }}</md-option>
        </md-select>
```

Comment: I also encountered this problem. What is your angular version?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to have `ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}"`

**DEMO**

```js
// Code goes here


var app = angular.module('app', ["ngMaterial"]);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.users  =[
            { id: 1, name: 'Bob' },
            { id: 2, name: 'Alice' },
            { id: 3, name: 'Steve' }
          ];
       $scope.selectedUser = { id: 1, name: 'Bob' };
      
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link data-require="angular-material@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-material@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-animate@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-aria@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div layout="row">
    <md-select placeholder="Select" ng-model="selectedUser">
      <md-option ng-repeat="user in users" value="{{user.name}}">
        {{user.name}}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi its not working for me . i did exctly the same 

i am using $mdpanel  and the form is in the dialog . 
when i click on the select i see in html . "area-expend" change ti true and immediately to false

Answer (score 1):

To make your select box initially load the selected item

Keep your code as it is

```
<md-select ng-model="ctrl.selectedUser" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}">
  <md-option ng-value="user" ng-repeat="user in ctrl.users">{{ user.name }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Check your Angular version it should be <= `1.5.9`

Demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZRwaQ?editors=1010

Comment: my version is 1.510

Comment: thx a lot its working 
do you know why I can't close the select outside the box  ? on modal

Comment: it is normal behaviour. When you click outside of select box it closes

Comment: - sorry i meant  I can not close it  on panel dialog
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42052162/click-outside-md-select-is-not-working

Comment: I don't know the reason