# Click outside md-select is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, md-select

select in dialog - angular material - mdpanel 
using sample md-select
but click outside the select when the options are open is not working.

how can I fix it ? 
thx a lot

html:

```
<md-select  ng-model="ctrl.selectedUser" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}">
         <md-option ng-value="user" ng-repeat="user in ctrl.users">{{ user.name }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed:

I have removed the "zIndex" property from md-panel or md-dialog config object